# Security of a Caesar cipher cascade

Tags: python, encryption, caesar-cipher

I'm attempting to make the Caesar cipher slightly more secure by first attaining the ciphertext and then running the ciphertext through the cipher to give a second ciphertext. Not entirely sure how to do this, would this be a loop of the algorithm. Could I just multiply the key*2?

Comment: That's not more secure.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please post what have you tried so far and take a look at how to ask good questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is not for any use, just to learn. I'm relatively new to programming

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can encrypt the ciphertext again with the second key, but the property of a Caesar cipher is that each character is encrypted on its own. You have no relation with other characters of the message. That is why you can repeatedly encrypt some plaintext with multiple keys, but this won't give you additional security, because all those keys can be compressed to a single key which does the same as the cascade in a single invocation.

Let's see an example. Let the message be "hi", the keys be 5, 2, 20 and the alphabet of size 26. This gives us the following intermediate and final ciphertexts:

```
c1: "mn"
c2: "op"
cf: "ij"
```

Which is of course the same as an encryption with the key `1`. Since our alphabet has the length 26, then the final key can be computed as `(5 + 2 + 20) % 26`.

You could implement a Vigenère cipher which is a much more secure *classical* cipher. It still has nowhere near the same security as modern block cipher like AES.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I now understand what I asked and how it's flawed. I'm trying to create a simple program that can encrypt and decrypt without the use of a commercial algorithm. I'm finding this extremely challenging with very little programming knowledge. Your response has helped clear somethings up for me, so thank you. 

I now realize I need to implement a much more secure algorithm.

Comment: I would caution against implementing a complex modern cipher like AES with only little programming knowledge. Although, there are modern ciphers like RC4 and Tiny Encryption Algorithm (TEA) which should be fairly easy to implement. Python supports all kinds of bit operations that are necessary to implement this. When you've implemented these, then you can look for test vectors to check your implementation for correctness.

Comment: @Meeata If you want to do it for learning purposes, go ahead. But if you intend in using it in an actual real world situation, [DON'T](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own)! The world's most accepted and secure encryption algorithms are open source (unless you're NSA) exactly because they need to be scrutinised by everyone. You'll find that most languages already implement the most popular algorithms and you're better off using those instead of implementing them yourself.

Comment: If you want to program a simple encryption method then have a look at [RC4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4).  It is not perfect, but it is absurdly easy to program and is a useful entrance into crypto programming.  As Reti43 says, just use RC4 for learning, do *not* use it for any real-world work.